# Can´t get seconds from timestamp of the firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the firebase database there is a data of type date in the collection, I retrieved the data but it came as `Timestamp(seconds=1569466800, nanoseconds=0)`, this is the code:

```
db.collection('processos').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setupDocs(snapshot.docs);
});

const setupDocs = (data) => {
    if (data.length) {
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const documento = doc.data();
            console.log(documento.dataEnvio)
        });
     }
};
```

I verified that it was an `object` using `typeof()` and using `console.log()`, but when i tried using `documento.dataEnvio.seconds` or `documemto.dataEnvio['seconds']` for example , it returned error "cannot read property".

i'm trying to convert the time stamp into date format

Comment: Please post your code where you handle the data retrieved from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

`documento = doc.data()` gives you an object that contains all of the field/value pairs in the document.  `documento.dataEnvio` will give you the value of the field called `dataEnvio`.  If `dataEnvio` is a Timestamp type field, you can get the seconds value out of that with `documento.dataEnvio.seconds`.

If you want a JavaScript Date type object, then use `documento.dataEnvio.toDate()`.  Be sure to read the API documentation for [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I tried documento.daataEnvio.seconds but it returned error cannot read property